# Record-triggered flow erroring with “Error Occurred: 0 recipients” despite successful recipient email address provision

Tags: email, visual-workflow

I have a record-triggered flow that is failing because cannot perform the ‘Send Email’ action.

It is ending with the error:

“Error Occurred: 0 recipients”

I can tell from the debugging log that all the criteria have been met in order to execute this action, and that the attempt was made, but when trying to send this email, the condition described by the error message was encountered.
I don’t see why there would be ‘0 recipients’ because I can clearly see from the debugging log that it pulled the email address {!$Record.ContactEmail} which I have populated in the ‘Recipient ID’ field of the ‘Send Email’ action configuration.

The information from the debugging log pertaining to the error is as follows:
**(special attention to the successfully pulled recipient email address
of 'catherine.cinciatta@jfs.ohio.gov')**

---

**An Error Occurred with Your "OFC Case Management Email to Case Notification" Flow**

You’ve received this email because an error occurred while your "OFC Case Management Email to Case Notification" flow was running. Debug this flow in Flow Builder.

Error element Send_Initial_Email_to_Contact (FlowActionCall).
0 recipients

**SEND EMAIL:** Send Initial Email to Contact
**Inputs:**
emailSubject = Initial Email to Contact on Case
emailBody = This is the initial email sent to the Contact email address when the contact is put on the case
recipientId = {!$Record.ContactEmail} (catherine.cinciatta@jfs.ohio.gov)

The following are first a screen shot of the flow, then a screen shot
of the offending Send Email action element configuration:

[image: Screen shot of Flow]

[image: Screen shot of Send Email action element]

In addition,
When I swapped in an Email Aert action instead of the Send Email action, this did not error.  It pulled the same contact email address as the one shown in the debug information for the failed flow, but the difference is, it was able to send it:

The following are screen shots of the Email Alert action element, and then a
screen shot of the Email Alert configuration:

[image: Screen Shot of Email Alert action element]

[image: Screen Shot of Email Alert configuration]

Any insight would be so helpful.

Thank you very much !
Cathy

Comment: Is Recipient ID supposed to be an Id?

Comment: Thank you so much @NickCook for your suggestion. As it turns out, yes,. you are right that that Recipient ID field DOES need to contain an actual Recipient ID (as opposed to an email address value). However, when I tried merely replacing {!$Record.ContactEmail} with {!$Record.ContactId} in the Recipient ID field (and nothing else), I still got the same 0 Recipient error.

Comment: ... Continuation...So, I then went on to realize that I could try populating my original {!$Record.ContactEmail} in the 'Recipient Address LIst field instead of the Recipient ID field and that did alleviate the flow error and go on to send the email out.

Comment: ... Continuation...However, it appears I still have multiple hurdles to get over, as far as getting this email correct. That might be worth another separate question on my part, though, if I can't get those things ironed out.